# Better alternatives to common command line tools?

Tags: command-line-interface

I've recently found some awesome replacements for common command line tools and wanted to share them and learn about others.

The three of these have made my recent troubleshooting much more efficient:

- [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) - ack is a tool like grep, designed for programmers with large trees of heterogeneous source code
- [dstat](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/) - replacement for vmstat, iostat, netstat, nfsstat and ifstat
- [mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) - mtr combines the functionality of the 'traceroute' and 'ping' programs in a single network diagnostic tool

What tools do you install because they're better than the defaults?

Comment: Who says those aren't the defaults?

Comment: Good point. I have this view because most of these tools describe themselves as replacements or combinations of other tools. They're also not installed by default with most linux distributions.

Comment: No, not again. We had similar question about good command line tools.

Comment: cygwin to replace to replace the windows ______ commands ;-)

Answer (score 1):

- [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) - "It is similar to top, but allows to scroll the list vertically and horizontally to see all processes and their full command lines."
- [links](http://links.sourceforge.net/) or [elinks](http://www.elinks.cz/) - replacements for lynx
- [gt5](http://gt5.sourceforge.net/) - du browser

Comment: htop looks very nice

Answer (score 1):

[sup](http://sup.rubyforge.org/) - gmail like command-line mail client (replacement for mutt).